# Blade is not showing section

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm following the laravel 5 tutorial by Jeffrey Way in Laracasts.com, in the blade 101 video Jeffrey writes a footer section which contains some Javascript, I tried to do the same but my 'footer' section is not showing, only the content section, I tried changing names and nothing. Here's the code:

**app.blade.php**

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div class="container">
    @yield('content')
  </div>

    @yield('footer')
  </body>
</html>
```

**contact.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
  <h1>Contact Me!</h1>
@stop

@section('footer')
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      alert("Joder!");
    })();
  </script>
@stop
```

I tried using just text instead of Javascript and it's the same, the footer section is not showing, also, if I change the 'content' for 'anythingelse' then the section stops showing too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app.blade.php replace

```
@yield('footer')
```

with

```
@section('footer')
@show
```

Then in your contact.blade.php replace the footer section with

```
@section('footer')
    @parent

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      alert("Joder!");
    })();
  </script>
@stop
```

Comment: Thank you Cyril, it works! although I was being such an idiot, it results that I had 2 app.blade.php, one in another directory, and I was trying to modify the one that was not being used.